# Are these too many foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm using MySQL and have been planning out the database structure for a system I'm building out. As I've been going along, I started to wonder if it was acceptable to have a particular foreign key constraint in many different tables. From what I understand, it would be fine, as it makes sense. But I'd like to double check.

For example, I have a users table, and I use the user_id as a foreign key for many tables, sometimes multiple times in one table. For example, I have a `one-to-one` relationship with a `user_settings` table, which of course stores the `user_id`. And then I have a companies table, which alone has a few references to the `user_id` key. In this case, I have a column that keeps track of the user that created the company in the system (`created_by`), a column for the main contact (`main_contact`, who is also a user of the system), and there might be another reference. So that alone, already has the `user_id` key being used as a foreign key constraint 3-4 times.

Just to add another bit of info, I have a tasks table and that of course needs to reference the `user_id` to keep track of who it's assigned to, and I also have another column that keeps track of the user that created the task. That would be `assigned_to` and `created_by`, respectively.

There are more tables though that reference back to that key. I might be up to 8 references already. I do believe I've designed it properly so far, but based on what I've mentioned, does this sound fine?

Comment: Your use of foreign keys seems reasonable.  In general, it is not uncommon to have more foreign keys in a well-designed database than tables.

Comment: Good use of foreign keys and normalization https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreign key usage seems fine to me - after all, you are simply representing logical relationships between your tables.

A user within your system interacts with the data in many ways, and to define these relationships your approach is the correct one.

The key point I think is that under a lot circumstances, you won't always want (or need) to make all the joins that represent your relationships - simply the ones that you need in that context.

Answer (score 0):

As per my undestanding the way you are defining is fine i.e to use a user id to many tables as foreign key.

If your line:: I have a companies table, **which alone has a few references to the user_id key** doesn't mean that you are using multipe user_id in same table and I know you are not.